# strings to array and locating a character in a string

Tags: c

i am working on a program where the input is an ID of 9 numbers :
program checks if the id is correct or not by :-

1. checking if the string is formed by numbers only .
2. every number has a weight of 1 or 2 so it should be 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
   1
3. multiply the weight and the number
4. if the number is bigger than 9 then add the numbers forming it .
5. if the number is from multiplication of 10 then the ID is correct ..

example :-
1   7   9   3   7   9   2   5   0-ID

1   2   1   2   1   2   1   2   1-Weight

1   14  9   6   7   18  2   10  0-num x weight

1   5   9   6   7   9   2   1   0-(4)

sum = 40 then it is a correct ID.

## I wrote most of it but then i noticed that it has to be a string . so my questions are :

1. is there a way to put a string into an array?as doing it with an
   array is way easier.
2. how do i locate a place in a string ? like if i want the third
   character in a string how do i locate it?.

and here is the code that i did it does not work yet and it needs alot of changes but i guess i will put it anyways :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 9
void input(int num[N]);
int check(int num[N]);
int main()
{
    int num[N],a;
    input(num);
    a = check(num);
    if (a = 1)
        printf("ID is correct");
    else printf("ID is NOT correct");

}
void input(int num[N])
{
    int i;
    printf("Enter your ID (9digits) :-");
    for (i = 0;i < N;i++)
        scanf("%d",num[i]);
}
int check(int num[N])
{
    int w[N] = { 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1 },wxnum[N],i,tota[N],sum,g;
    for (i = 0;i < N;i++)
        wxnum[i] = num[i] * w[i];
    for (i = 0;i < N;i++)
    {
        if (wxnum[i] > 9)
            tota[i] = wxnum[i] / 10 + wxnum[i] % 10;
        else tota[i] = wxnum[i];
    }
    sum = tota[0] + tota[1] + tota[2] + tota[3] + tota[4] + tota[5] + tota[6] + tota[7] + tota[8];
    g = sum % 10;
    if (g = 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;

}
```

***Thanks everyone for your help.***

Comment: You have a typo: `if (a = 1)` --> `if (a == 1)` and `if (g = 0)` --> `if (g == 0)`. Compile with all warnings enabled.

Comment: In C, a "string" is an array of `char` with an extra '\0' at the end. You access each individual letter just like any other array.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp ah srry , do you know of a way to turn the warnings on . i am using visual studio and it does not show me any warning only errors and not all of them .

Comment: @JohnnyMopp ok but how can like add the number in forth place to a number in the forth place in an array. in an array i would use for and [i] but it does not work with a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a string by doing

```
/*N is defined as 9 in your code.*/
/*Considering there is always a '\0' in every string, we should allocat N + 1 slot for your nine numbers and the extra '\0'.*/

char chStr[N + 1];    
scanf("%s", chStr);
```

After you got the string, you can take advantage of the values of charactor '0' - '9' (their values are from 48 to 57 correspondingly) in ASCII table, and easily transfer the charactors into integers by doing:

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
  chStr[i] = chStr[i] - '0';
}
```

If you are restrict on the type, you can transfer these char values into int values by adding extra two lines:

```
int num[N];
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
  chStr[i] = chStr[i] - '0';
  num[i] = (int) chStr[i];
}
```

Please note that my code didn't check the validation of user input. To make it more secure, you can use

```
scanf("%9s", chStr);
```

to declare the maximum length that the user can input.

Comment: You need to give the array a name.  Also, `scanf("%s", array_name);` (missing quotes)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you! I have made some mistakes, including the missing quotes and variable naming. I just corrected them.

Comment: @zhugen tho what i am trying to do is take an id from the user and if it has letters the then it is incorrect and ask him to type it again.if i changed the letter to a number it wont be the correct id .

Comment: @Drat018 you can use the conbination of sscanf() and strlen() to check if the user input is valid. `char chStrTmp[N+1]; sscanf(chStr, "%[0-9]", chStrTmp); if (strlen(chStr) == strlen(chStrTmp) {//"input is valid"})` sscanf() function stops copying chStr to chStrTmp once it finds the current charactor is not a number, thus chStrTmp's length will be shorter. That's how it works.

Comment: @zhugen is there a way to do it without sscanf as we have not learned this function and my proff wont accept my homework.and do you know a way to locate a position in a string  as for example i need to add the number in forth place to the weight corresponding to it.in an array it would have been

Comment: @Drat018 I am not sure I am understanding you properly. If you are not allowed to use sscanf, you can just check the validation of each letter in your string by simply using `if (chStr[i] >= '0' && chStr[i] <= '9')`.

Comment: @zhugen ya i got that but idk how do i scan each letter/number in a string (scan them one by one) for example lets assume someone entered 03194t3g31  i want to scan each and every one of the numbers/ letters alone. and if there is a letter then let the user enter the number again for example lets assume he enters 064951358 then its all good and program continues running .(if possible i want the number to transfer from string to array)

Comment: Perhaps you can also try function atoi. `int nNum = atoi(chStr)`.